# Is there a way to save a function as a variable or a space as a variable?

Tags: java

for example

```
int[] array = int[5];
int x = int[0];
//now x would be null
x = 5;
//now x is 5, but int[0] is still null.
```

is there a way to also change int[0] when I change x without
int[0] = x ?

Have not tried anything yet. Dont even know if such a thing is possible.

Comment: Note the elements of a *primitive* integer array default to `0`, not `null`. As for you question: No, it's not possible to do that in Java.

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't see how your question title is related to the question you asked. How is saving a function related to an array of `int`?

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `array[0]` to `x`, it creates a new variable `x` and copies the value of `array[0]` into it. Any changes made to `x` will not affect `array[0]` because `x` is a separate variable that holds its own value.

If you want `array[0]` to be updated whenever `x` is changed, you need to explicitly assign the value of `x` back to `array[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```java
Integer[] array = new Integer[5];  // i.e. array = [null,null,null,null,null]
Integer x = array[0];              // x == null
x = 5;                             // x == 5, array[0] == null
```

***P.S.** `Integer` is a wrapper over the `int`. This is the `Object`. So `Integer` can be `null`, which is default value. But `int` can't be null, and default value is `0`.*

Comment: Assuming that @AmandaTan is new to Java, maybe you should [edit] your answer and explain that `Integer` is a class that is generally used to wrap an `int` primitive? Maybe you should also explain that class `Integer` is immutable and therefore the statement `x = 5;` uses auto-boxing (and un-boxing) to create a new `Integer` instance that wraps the `int` value of 5 and therefore `x` no longer points to the same instance that it did after the statement: `Integer x = array[0];`.